# grunt-contrib-sass task starts running but doesn't finish

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I'm trying to set up Grunt to compile sass when changes are made (using grunt-contrib-watch) in a simple project using Express.  My gruntfile has a "server" task which I use to run my application; this task compiles the sass and runs the application.

The initial compilation of the sass when starting the server works correctly. However changes when the application is running are detected and the task appears to start but it never seems to complete.  **Below is a copy of my output**:

```
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
File public/stylesheets/main.css created.

Running "concurrent:main" (concurrent) task
Running "watch" task
Waiting...Running "nodemon:main" (nodemon) task
2 Jun 19:55:25 - [nodemon] v0.7.10
2 Jun 19:55:25 - [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
2 Jun 19:55:25 - [nodemon] watching: C:\Development\grunt-test
2 Jun 19:55:25 - [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
OK
>> File "assets\stylesheets\main.scss" changed.

Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
```

The sass task never finishes.  This only seems to happen when I run my "server" task, if I run the "watch" task it works correctly.

Here is my **Gruntfile.js** which reproduces the issue:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        sass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    style: 'compressed'
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'assets/stylesheets',
                    src: ['*.scss'],
                    dest: 'public/stylesheets',
                    ext: '.css'
                }]
            }
        },

        nodemon: {
            main: {}
        },

        watch: {
            scss: {
                files: 'assets/stylesheets/**/*',
                tasks: ['compile']
            }
        },

        concurrent: {
            main: {
                tasks: ['nodemon', 'watch'],
                options: {
                    logConcurrentOutput: true
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-nodemon');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-concurrent');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');

    grunt.registerTask('compile', ['sass']);
    grunt.registerTask('server', ['compile', 'concurrent']);
};
```

Here is my **package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "grunt-test",
  "description": "grunt-test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.x",
    "debug": "0.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.5.3",
    "grunt-nodemon": "^0.1.2",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^0.4.3",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^0.7.3"
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old one, but I was coming up against the same errors.

I swapped out grunt-contrib-sass for grunt-sass and it worked as it should.